# Who can participate in Play Store closed testing?

Tags: android, testing, google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

https://play.google.com/console/about/closed-testing/

Google Play Store Closed Testing

Is it possible that people that I don't add to the testers list can test the app?
Is there something like registered testers that can test the app? Or is there any other way that other people can test my app without making it avaiable to the public (Open testing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In the test module of Google Play Console, you have three different choices:

- Internal tests
- Close Tests
- Open Tests

You should go for *Open Tests*. You can choose unlimited or limited number of public testers. If you choose *X* limited people, only *X* people will see your app on the store and will be able to download, test your app, and provide feedback.